# Display content of subdomain in root domain - rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, dns

I have a landing page hosted at `landing.mydomain.com` at certain static web host.

My application is running on a server to which `mydomain.com` is pointing to.

Is there anyway using `.htaccess` to show display to my visitors the content of `landing.mydomain.com` when they visit `mydomain.com`?

If not `.htaccess` is there a good way to do this. I dont want to move my landing page to my application server just yet. Looking for options. Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava you mean setting up a reverse proxy kinda thing to from `mydomain.com` to `get.mydomain.com`? And serving all other requests from the app server?

Comment: @anubhava Im on nginx btw. Could you help out with the rewrite rules please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `nginx` config you can use this code on `domain.com` to enable `proxy_pass` to `landing.mydomain.com`:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass       http://landing.mydomain.com;
   proxy_set_header Host      $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```